# How to iterate a CSV file in bash?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

How to iterate file which has comma separated by value ?

I tried the following:

```
$ cat file | tr ','  '\n' > /tmp/f1
$ while read -r line;do 
   echo $line;
done < /tmp/f1
```

How can i iterate over the first line contents without the creation of temporary file?

Any ideas?

Comment: It does not make sense to iterate a file to just `echo $line` (the iteration must imply something more). Otherwise, for just printing lines: `tr',''\n' <file` would be enough

Comment: It looks like you've already written some code to do this -- in what way does it not do what you need?  If there's an error message, or any other problem in the output, please include that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all, [avoid doing text-parsing with shell loops](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/22222). It is hard to do, easy to get wrong and very hard to read. And slow. Very, very, slow. Instead, use something like `awk` which is specifically designed to read by "fields". For example, with this input file:

```
foo, bar, baz
oof, rab, zab
```

You can read each comma-separated field using `awk -F,` to set the field separator to `,`:

```
$ awk -F, '{ print "The 1st field is",$1,"the 2nd", $2,"and the 3rd", $3}' file
The 1st field is foo the 2nd  bar and the 3rd  baz
The 1st field is oof the 2nd  rab and the 3rd  zab
```

---

Even if you insist on doing it in the shell, you don't need the temp file and you don't need `tr`. You can tell `while read` to separate on commas:

```
$ while IFS=, read -r one two three; do 
    echo "The 1st field is $one, the 2nd $two and the 3rd $three"; 
  done < file
The 1st field is foo, the 2nd  bar and the 3rd  baz
The 1st field is oof, the 2nd  rab and the 3rd  zab
```

Answer (score 3):

Fields in a csv file could span several lines, for this reason and others, it's why I preferred to use [xsv](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv) when I had to parse csv.

One way to parse a csv file with bash and xsv can be :

```bsh
csvFile="myfile.csv"
lengthItems=$((($(xsv count "$csvFile") - 1 ))) # -1 because for loop start at 0

for i in $( seq 0 "$lengthItems" ); do

    row="$(xsv slice -i "$i" "$csvFile")" # real magic happening here

    # Do what you want with your $row here  
    
done
```